# How to make sure a substring is a part some string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that takes two strings from the user. The program should verify that that s_short is a substring of s_long and if s_short is found inside s_long the program should print the index position at where the s_short occurs in s_long. If s_short is not a substring of s_long, your program should print -1. Example

```
RESTART 
Enter the long string: aaaaaa
Enter the short string: aa
0 1 2 3 
RESTART  
Enter the long string: aaaaaaa
Enter the short string: ab
-1
```

That is my code but it doesn't work

```
s_long=input("Enter a long string:")
s_short=input("Enter a short string:")
for index, s_short in enumerate(s_long):
  if (len(s_short))>=0:

        print(index)

else:
    print("-1")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: take a look at the `re` module or use conditional `in` to test if short string is in long string

Comment: visit www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Please fix the indentation on your code; it is impossible to tell what the `else:` belongs with.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you deleted your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390801/write-a-program-that-takes-two-strings-from-the-user-the-program-should-verify) on this? It doesn't look like much has changed in 5 hours ago...

Comment: I thought I figured it out but hadnt

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
try:
    print s_long.index(s_short)
except ValueError:
    print -1
```

EDIT: There's actually a find method, which does exactly the same as all of above:

```
print s_long.find(s_short) # -1 if not found
```

EDIT: If you need *all* indices at which substring occurs, you can use Python's `re` module.